# Swap selected item from dialog to listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to swap item from Dialog to ListView. Say for Example i have a list. Player 1, Player 2 and Player 3. Once i select an item from the list, say player 1. Dialog Opens with Player 2 and Player 3. After selecting Player 3 from the Dialog. The List should be like Player 3, Player 2, Player 1.

ListView items starting order:

Player 1
Player 2
Player 3

Dialog Order:
Player 2 
Player 3

After swap

Player 3
Player 2
Player 1

How can this be done? Any Algo or Sample Code would be Appreciated. Thank You.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

This is what i am trying.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {



                 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                    dialog.setTitle(playerData.getDisplayPlayerName());
                    final ListView wrActivePlayerList = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.activePlayerListName);
                    final ArrayAdapter<String> activePlayer = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, qbActivePlayer);
                     wrActivePlayerList.setAdapter(activePlayer);

                      wrActivePlayerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                  int arg2, long arg3) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                              System.out.println("Item Clicked");
                                TextView playerName = (TextView)playerDataView.findViewById(R.id.playername);
for (int i = 0;i < ((ViewGroup) playerDataView).getChildCount(); i++)
                                    {
//                                             TextView txtView = (TextView)((ViewGroup) playerDataView).getChildAt(i); //(TextView) ((ViewGroup) playerDataView).getChildAt(i);
                                        TextView txtView = (TextView)playerDataView.findViewById(R.id.widget_lineupview_playerdata_playername);
                                       if (txtView != null)
                                       {
                                           if (txtView.getText() == qbActivePlayer[arg2])
                                           {
                                               txtView.setText(playerData.getDisplayPlayerName());
                                           }
                                       }
                                    }                                       playerName.setText(wrActivePlayer[arg2]);
}
});
```

Comment: if you  are using String[] for the data for your adapter, then you can  do simple assignment of the player selected from the listview with the one selected from the dialog having both indexes, and then you will have to call notifyDatasetChanged to refresh the listview and show the new data

Comment: Hi Saksak, Thanks for the suggestion.Really appreciated. Yes i am using String[] for the data. Do you have any sample code ??Just trying to picturing .  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change position of elements on main list. When you pick first and second elements, on first position need put the second element and for second element put in the first position. After when you swap position on list, just recreate a new listview.

Sample code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        values.add("Android");
        values.add("iPhone");
        values.add("WindowsMobile");        
    }
```

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt; adapter = new ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt;(this,
                R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        values.remove(position);
        //here I put item on 0 position
        values.add(0, item);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onResume();
    }
}
```

rowlayout.xml

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

```
 &lt;ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon" 
            android:layout_width="22px" 
            android:layout_height="22px" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px" 
            android:layout_marginRight="10px" 
            android:layout_marginTop="4px" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        &lt;/ImageView&gt;
```

```
&lt;TextView
        android:id="+id/label1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="+id/label" 
        android:textSize="20px" >
    &lt;/TextView&gt;
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you. I am trying to learn. Do you have any sample code? Thank you